# Is time taveling possible according to Hinduism?

Tags: scripture, adi-shankaracharya, time, consciousness

Not necessarily sending body to past or future but also transferring consciousness to different time periods.Is it supported in Hindu scriptures?
The only time I know about transfering consciousness was when Adi Sankara transferred his consciousness to a dying king...but as far as i know that king might ve been a contemporary of Sankaracharya.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria if there is reference to sending our body to another time period( as normally denoted by the term time traveling) that is ok too...

Comment: Time travel is not possible because travelling to past/future is not allowed.. transferring of consciousness is one of the astma siddhi... Bhogar, Agasthyar also had.. even some Asuras had like flight, transferring of consciousness to goat body and get killed and retrieved..

Comment: Yes it is possible. There is a story about somebody on earth traveling to brahmaloka and staying there for a day. Since one day in brahmaloka is equal to thousands of years on earth, after that person returns to earth, he finds that thousands of years have elapsed.

Comment: @PrasannaR is this siddhi attainable in modern period? Please give reference to scriptures

Comment: @LazyLubber Yes...I have read it too..This is the story of Kakudmi from 9th canto of Bhagvata Purana...I Think this is an example of time dilation rather than time traveling...

Comment: I think you need to ask tantric expert, you need to get initiated in particular mantra and daily do the japa for specified no. of time.. and during eclipse full time.. chant the same, it will happen normally like the food you had taken had to be digest will be converted to siddhi the main problem with siddhi is its detrimental to the practitioner it wont lead to moksha.. the practitioner will be using the siddhi and reveling in the same plane..

Comment: Time travel assumes the reality of time. but this cannot be established.

Comment: Going into the future through time dilation is possible, and is recorded in the Puranas: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation

Comment: @Ikshvaku Time dilation is not really time travelling. Huge difference.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria true.I think a lot of ppl confuse between these two...

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Future time travel is possible through time dilation, you speed up other people's time while keeping yours the same.

Comment: Using logic if time travel if at all is possible for Future and it should be possible for past.. This Nyaya logic. so according to logic if you are able to do time dilation to future and the past is possible also, since the second is false is time dilation by logic your premise that time dilation is time travel is nullified by null hypothesis :-)